# Seeking advice on how to rearrange existing breakers and add 2 circuits, including a 20A GFCI/AFCI breaker in a split-bus GE panel

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

My panel is a GE TX1612RH split-bus 125A panel (photo below).  It is an outdoor panel, vintage 1980 when home was built.  I want to run two 20A circuits to a shed 60-ft away and would like to know if the following changes are advisable and in accordance with Code:  1) Move the 2-pole 30A (thin) breaker for A/C to the slot immediately above the 50A "Sub-Main" breaker, thereby consolidating all 240V loads in upper portion (I think the A/C contractor goofed on the electrical portion); 2) Install a 20A "thin" breaker in lower-left slot for a dedicated circuit for an in-wall 120V shed heater (blank-face GFCI will be upstream of in-wall heater); and 3) Install a "full-width" 20A GFCI/AFCI breaker for everything else in the shed, using the slots formerly used by the 2-pole 30A breaker.  Regarding #1: Is it OK to use "thin" breakers in the upper bus, or should I replace the 30A thin breakers with the full-width variety.  Many thanks!

Update #1:  Photo of panel interior has been added.  Unfortunately, there are no placards or labels on inside of panel door or on back side of cover, so I'm driving "blind."  Googling the "K849 *" reference (top of back of panel), I found nothing.

Update #2:  The A/C contractor (in 2008) used very MINIMAL wire to reach the 2-pole compact 30A breaker -- not enough wire to extend to the new and proper position of a full-width 2-pole 30A breaker above the existing 2-pole 50A breaker.  Any suggestions for a remedying this dilemma?  Rules for using red-head connectors wrapped in rubber and vinyl electrical tape?  Or must I pull a new run of #10 copper conductors?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo of the labeling on the inside of your panel's door please?

Comment: My panel is a similar GE split bus with 150 A service. If you want to reopen this post, I will give an answer. In my panel the ac is powered by a full sized 2 inch wide 40 A breaker in the upper section.

Comment: Yes, and the Eel is looking for the data label that includes model number, screw torques, accessories, and a diagram of the panel layout.

Comment: How are you running two 120V circuits to a shed without violating NEC 225.30?  Will one of them be on a switch?

Comment: Thanks.  I don't have the NEC text (I presume you have to purchase) but thought I could run separate neutrals for the 2 circuits (one dedicated, and one shared).  Now I know better. 
 What kind of switch would make a 2nd circuit legal?  Would I need a subpanel for both circuits inside the shed?

Comment: @Marty -- can you get us photos of that label on the inside front cover? Why are you wanting to put the shed lighting on GFCI?

Comment: Hi, Eel:  Unfortunately no labels, placards, etc., anywhere in the panel, so I'm not even sure of the panel's amperage, but other posts suggest either 125A or 150A (determining the gauge of the service feed wires has been difficult). Shed lighting will share a circuit with all the receptacles, which include a weatherproof outlet where power first enters the shed. With our heavy snowfalls, I'd like GFCI protection either at that first outlet or at the breaker.  Hoping two 20A 120V circuits to shed will be legal if each is fed by a breaker in the "Rule-of-Six" panel area (see Monica's comment).

Answer (score 2):

This is a split bus aka rule-of-six panel.  They were originally developed because breakers over 60A were cost prohibitive (no longer true).  They are outlawed now, and are dangerous because nothing prevents you from overloading the service.

They were allowed *when* a load calculation was done that showed the house would not overload the service; however, when people add circuits they don't bother to do another load calculation, and that's the danger. Normally a large load like  the A/C would be put in the Rule of Six area; putting it in the Lighting area makes me wonder if they did a load calc and it went badly. Any idea what came out of that space?

### GE and their double-stuff rejection system

GE has a funny way of doing double-stuff breakers.  All their bus stabs look like normal bus stabs, a flat horizontal blade maybe 3/8" to 1/2" wide.  **However, on spaces enabled for double-stuff breakers, they have a vertical rod - I call it a "cruciform" for the way it crosses the bus stab**.  The double-stuff (1/2" wide single and 1" wide 2-pole) clip onto this cruciform.

In 1966 NEC added "CTL" rules limiting the number of double-stuffs in a panel. They required mechanical keying to reject double-stuffs where not allowed, so most builders notched their bus-bars and came out with "CTL" breakers which would reject in a normal space. (as well as non-CTL breakers to support pre-1966 panels, haha, guess what everyone did).  **GE simply *omits* the cruciform.  Which means, there's no way to trick a double-stuff where GE doesn't allow it**.

In a split-bus aka "Rule of Six" panel, there can only be six breaker throws to de-energize the whole panel.  So there would be no earthly reason for GE to install the double-stuff-enabling cruciform in those spaces.

Now, this panel only supports four full-size 2-pole breakers in the "Rule of Six" section. You might think GE intends you to use three 1" wide 2-pole breakers per side.  Looking closely, it appears the cruciforms are in exactly the right place to support just that - note there is no cruciform on the top half of the top space, so you can't put a 1/2" wide 1-pole there. You'd have to leave that empty.

### You can't run 2 120V circuits out to a shed, anyway

[Rule 225.30 says](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/104141/47125) you can only run one circuit to an outbuilding. The rule intends that be a feeder to a subpanel.  However, there are certain exceptions:

- A different-voltage circuit is OK, and this is where I'll introduce you to the **multi-wire branch circuit**. This is a 120/240V circuit with 120V loads placed between one of the two hots and the shared neutral. You can also power 240V loads between the two hots (but the breaker must be 2-pole if you do that).
- If one of the circuits is switched from the supply end, then it's OK.  So if you are hellbound and determined to have 2 independent circuits, find a believable pretense to put a switch on one. (e.g. so you don't have to put your shoes back on to switch off the forgotten shed lights).

### Breaker strategies

One option is to get a full-size 2-pole 30A breaker, place it in the open position, and use it for the A/C.  This will require extending the A/C cables, but you can do that with normal (well, large red or tan) wire nuts.

That frees up the 2 double-stuff spaces for 2 thin breakers (or a 20A 2-pole for an MWBC).

Another option is just get two full-size 1-pole 20A breakers and put them in the Rule of Six area and use them for your new circuits. You still only have five throws to turn everything off, so that's legit. *Nowhere is it written that circuits in the Rule of Six area must be 240V.*

- You could also get one 1/2" and one full-size breaker in that Rule of Six area, if that matches the current knockouts that are removed from the panel cover.
- For that matter, you could put three 1/2" breakers in the Rule of Six area, because that will be only six throws.  Keep in mind for future, heh, expansion in this very full and obsolete/dangerous panel.

*Any now-empty breaker knockouts need to be filled with a blanking plate - you can't have curious fingers finding bus bars.  I find those blanking plates to be expensive, hard to find and very flimsy - so I prefer to arrange panels so all holes are full of real breakers. Which are not flimsy.*

Comment: Monica:  Thank you!  If I understand the above, I could LEGALLY run two 20A 120V circuits to my shed, provided I feed them with two full-size 1-pole 20A (GFCI/AFCI) breakers in my Rule of Six Area.  If so, I'd leave my 2-pole 30A breaker for A/C where it's at and run five #12's (2 hots, 2 neutrals, and a ground wire) in 1/2" rigid conduit to a weatherproof receptacle on the outside of my shed, then go from there.  I would also have a 20A single-pole switch on the dedicated circuit (for powering the heater on/off) but INSIDE the shed. Heater is hard-wired; has a thermostat but no on/off switch.

Comment: But as I wrote my panel GE TX1615F FLUSH MOUNT 150 AMPERE the sticker indicates the left side will accept three compact 2-pole breakers and would leave two open 1/2 inch spaces. If the bus bar is the right shape then could it be that a 1-pole 20 A breaker would fit there to go to the shed? Or is the shape of the bus bar connection designed to exclude placing a 1-pole 1/2 inch breaker in the top and bottom? Right now I don't want to pull a breaker and see. Only one half slot could be filled to satisfy the rule of six.

Comment: In my case only one open half slot could be filled to satisfy the rule of six. Right now my my upper section if filled with four full size 2-pole breakers: 30 A, 40 A, 50 A, 60 A for dryer, a/c, range, main, respectively. I could replace the 50 A with a 40 A for our current range.

Comment: @Marty you're right on track, EXCEPT the switch must be at the house. See my two exceptions to 225.30.

Comment: OK, thanks, Harper.  I misinterpreted your "breaker" comments --thought putting the two 1-pole 20A breakers in the Rule-of-Six area would qualify both as "switches at the supply end."  The panel is outdoors on my patio and 60' from the shed, so the best place for the switch would be on the patio next to the panel.  Will give consideration to a Plan B: a subpanel in the shed, an MWBC, a main lug panel, or dropping the in-wall heater which would obviate the need for a dedicated circuit.

Comment: @Harper:  I'd like to go with the MWBC strategy you outlined above.  I'll reconnect my A/C to a full-size 2-pole 30A breaker in my Rule-of-Six area, and use the freed-up thin slots for a 2-pole 20A breaker.  I do not need 240V, so will "split" the hots at the shed into two 120V circuits -- one for my 1000W in-wall heater, and one for all else (lights and receptacles).  GFCI protection to be provided by a blank-face GFCI for the heater, and a GFCI receptacle for the other 120V brancht.  Question:  Will such a strategy satisfy the dedicated-circuit requirement for the heater?  Thanks much!

Comment: @Harper:  Can you confirm that the MWBC strategy above DOES need to be on a 2-pole 20A breaker (even though I'll never need or use 240V), and that this strategy obviates the requirement for a switch on the "supply" end?  Many thanks!

Comment: @Harper:  My understanding is that I am obligated to use a 2-pole 20A breaker in order to satisfy the "one-circuit-only" rule of NEC 225.30, but the only way I could possibly satisfy the dedicated-circuit requirement for my 120V in-wall heater is to never use both hots together for 240V.

Comment: @Marty "Switch on the supply end" is not what the requirement is: read the actual NEC 225.30 rule. The requirement is for different *characteristics*.  I plainly said that a "light switch" style switch at the house will satisfy that requirement.  You keep morphing that into "a switch at the shed" (nope) or "the breaker itself" (nope).  Stop doing that please :)  You need to have a plausible pretense, justifiable to the inspector, that your second circuit has a different characteristic. It could be "control the heater from the house so I don't forget and leave it on", works for me :)

Comment: As far as the MWBC, short version: **In this panel you must use a 2-pole breaker** either 2" or 1" wide.  You can't use two singles. Handle-ties don't work in a GE panel because of their weird approach to double-stuff breakers; a handle-tie won't enforce phasing like it would in any other panel.  The MWBC itself satisfies the "1 circuit" rule, *since an MWBC is one circuit*.

Comment: @Harper, thanks.  How about this then:  I'll install a weatherproof switch close to the panel to control one phase of the 2-pole 20 amp circuit (for the heater), and continue the always-on phase and the switched phase on to the shed.in conduit coming out of the weatherproof box used for the switch.  Would that be kosher?

Comment: @Marty yes, I think you're there.

Comment: @Harper:  Thanks very much.  I'd like (additionally) to put a switch on the heater circuit in the shed.  Not interested in making the two switches 3-way -- just want to get "legal" by having the weatherproof switch near the panel and having the option to turn the heater on/off while in the shed, as well.  Sound OK, or will that sound an alarm of some sorts for an inspector?

Comment: @Marty No, that'll be fine.

Comment: @Harper:  I decided to go with a 2-pole 20A GFCI breaker for the MWBC to my shed.  Must I pigtail all neutrals AND all hot wires to my receptacles?

Comment: @Marty As far as the MWBC is concerned, you only need to pigtail neutrals.  You can use the recep to splice hots.

Comment: @Harper:  Hello again!  I am striking out with my shed's MWBC; my 2-pole 20A GFCI breaker keeps tripping.  I have a switch at the panel controlling Phase B (dedicated to an in-wall heater) and have everything else in the shed (lights and receptacles) on Phase A.  Neutrals are all pigtailed. Hots are "spliced" through the receptacles.  Just 3 receptacles on Phase A thus far -- wanted to test early on. It's a head-scratcher.
 What would you recommend for a "next step" for troubleshooting?  Use a 1-pole 20A breaker to test each phase individually?  My 2-pole breaker is in the Rule-of-Six area.

Comment: @Marty Divide and conquer. Unplug everything plugged in - see if that clears it.  Then around the halfway point (in boxes not distance) disconnect the hots and neutral and see if that clears it.   You'll find the point where disconnecting at point X clears the problem but connecting the next bit causes it to fail. Your trouble lies in between.  Could be a ground wire touching a neutral terminal.

Comment: @Harper:  Thanks again -- problem was easy to isolate.  Had used bare copper pigtails (instead of greens) for grounding my receptacles and one had gotten too close to a receptacle's hot terminal when I'd closed up the switch box.  All is well now.  2-pole 20A GFCI breaker was ~$95 at Home Depot but far preferable to the alternative of installing multiple GFCI receptacles.

Answer (score 1):

In my very similar GE panel the sticker diagram indicates that the upper section will NOT accept compact 2-pole breakers (1 inch wide) on the right side, but will accept them on the left side.

The simplest way to connect your ac in the upper section would be to use a full sized 30A 2-pole breaker in the upper right. These are very cheap, but you would have to work on the panel hot. I have changed breakers in the lower section of my panel without switching off the 60 A main breaker, but the upper section presents greatly increased risk if you would make a mistake or if the breaker was defective in a certain way (shorted internally) which I must assume never occurs in practice.

The diagram on the sticker in my panel shows that compact 2-pole breakers MUST be inserted in a way not immediately obvious to an inexperienced person, but clearly correct when you think about it. The compact 2-pole breaker must be ASTRIDE (bridging) two full slots. It cannot be placed in one full slot. It will not snap in and it would not work there because both contacts in a full slot are on the same leg.

In my panel if I wanted to increase the number of 2-pole breakers in the upper section from four to five, then the two full sized 2-pole breakers on the left would be removed and three compact breakers put in their place.

Note the compact 2-pole breakers will snap in ONLY astride two (full) slots and can only work if they are astride two full slots. Starting at the top left the top half slot (1/2 inch)is left open, then the three compact 2-pole breakers are placed, then the bottom half slot is left open.

Note that in your panel the compact 30 A 2-pole breaker in the lower section is astride two full (1 inch wide) slots. If you ever move it, it must be inserted that way.